# Distributing stones into buckets (not trivial) / Integer Bin Packing Upper bound

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, bin-packing, buckets, upperbound

Suppose you have k stones and m stone types 
You have f1 stones from the first type, f2 from the second and so on.

(i.e. sum(f_i) = k).

In addition, we are given a positive integer r.

What is the minimal number of buckets needed, such that we could distribute the stone types into buckets where the size of every bucket is no more than r?
(We also know that for every i, f_i <= r).

This question is actually some kind of bin packing, so I'm not sure it has an exact answer but can we give it an upper bound?

An example of a trivial upper bound is m, as this will allow us to pack each stone type in 
his own bucket.

An example of a bound which doesn't work is k/r.
The reason is that if k=9, r=3 and we have 5 stone types, f1 = 2, f2 = 2, f3 = 2, f4 = 2, f5=1,

Then no matter how we partition the stone types, there has to be a bucket of size >= 4.

**All stones from the same type has to go to the same bucket.**

Any suggestions :) ?

EDIT: m and the f_i's are unknown, and I'm looking for a bound which enables me to distribute the stones for all (m,f_i's) combination.

Another example:
Suppose that r = 3.
I'll prove that k/2 buckets are enough:

Let's denote by x the number of types for which there are 3 stones.
y will denote the number of type from which there are exactly 2 stones, and z will the denote the number of single-stone types.

By definition:
3x + 2y + z = k.
We can allocate x buckets for the 3-stones types.

If (y > z) {first case}:
Fit one of the y types, together with one of the z types in a bucket {we have z such buckets}.

Fit the rest of the y types one at a bucket.

Since y > z we have used exactly x+y buckets, and since 3x + 2y + z = k => x+y <= k/2.

If (z >= y) {second case}:
It's easy to see that we can fit all stones in k/3 buckets (every bucket can be full, containing exactly 3 stones).

Also, for r=3, this bound it tight (if x=z=0 and y=k/2, then we need exactly k/2 buckets).

Now the question is: does the k/2 buckets bound hold for all r values?

I can show that a lower bound (i.e. a tight instance) of 2k/(r+1) buckets, but it's pretty far from k/2. Can anyone tighten the bound?

Comment: Are stones of the same type required to go into the same bucket?

Comment: Or on the contrary stones of same type can't go into single bucket?

Comment: I have to say it is pretty annoying that such an obvious question was not addressed up-front, when clearly the OP is assuming either my constraint or yours (@Suor), or some crazy constraint.

Comment: If the stones from the same type must be in the same bucket, I don't see how this is any different from the Bin Packing problem...

Comment: @Andrey, sorry if the question isn't written right.
If you have a more informative title, please edit/ write it here and I'll edit. Thanks !

Comment: @RonTeller,@Andrey- all stones of the same type has to go to the same bucket.

This is Bin Packing with integer sizes, but like I mentioned, I'm not looking for an exact answer, but an upper bound.


In the problem I'm having, m is unknown, and all I know is that the number of stones of each type is no more than r and the total number of stones is k.

Therefore the best bound I have at the moment is k (which is an upper bound on m).

I'm guessing that k/2 also holds, but I'm straggling with proving/disproving it.

k is a correct upper bound, k/r isn't (see my example in the opening post).

Comment: "m is unknown" - another fairly significant constraint.

Comment: If you're not solving instances of this problem, but trying to determine some fundamental and general property of it, shouldn't this be on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @harold I doubt it's really a research-level question, so [cstheory.se] probably isn't all that appropriate, but [cs.se] might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [first-fit algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-fit_algorithm) for the bin packing problem with almost no modifications necessary:

1. Generate a list `L` containing `m` integers, each represents the number of stones of each type.
2. Sort the list in descending order.
3. Create a new bucket
4. Run through `L` from the beginning to end, if adding the current element of `L` to the bucket doesn't exceed `r`, add to the bucket and remove it from `L`.
5. If `L` is empty, return the number of buckets. Else go back to step 3.

This algorithm is an approximation of `11/9*OPT + 6/9`, which is pretty decent and in most cases given a very good result.

The running type of this algorithm is `O(m log m)`. If `m` is not given, to create the list you need to count the number of stones of each type, which takes `O(L)` time and the whole procedure will take `O((m log m) + L)` time.

Comment: To be clarified by OP, but I suspect you're **just** given `k` and `r`, not all the actual stones (other "m is unknown" is a pointless constraint).

Comment: Thanks @Ron, but I'm afraid I might have mislead you in the original question :(.

m, and the f_i's are unknown, and I'm looking for a bound which works for all m/f_i combination.

If you look at the (edited :/) question, I give an example that shows that if r = 3, then k/2 buckets are enough the packing the stones.

I can also show that 2k/(r+1) are a minimal requirement for that, but I still have a huge gap I'm trying to narrow.